Discrepancy in perturbation analysis of infinite tetration at $x = e^{-e}$
It's known that the infinite tetration of $e^{-e}$ results in $\frac1e$.
So I decided to do a bit of perturbation analysis, if you make a shift $\frac1e - \epsilon$, then applying $x_{n+1} =\left(e^{-e}\right)^{x_n}$, where $x_0 = \frac1e - \epsilon$ should make $x_n$ converge to $\frac1e$.
$$x_1 = e^{-1+e\epsilon} \approx \frac1e\left(1+e\epsilon+\frac{e^2\epsilon^2}2\right) = \frac1e+\epsilon+\frac{e\epsilon^2}2$$
$$x_2 = e^{-1-e\epsilon-\frac{e^2\epsilon^2}2}\approx\frac1e\left(1-e\epsilon+\frac{e^2\epsilon^2}2\right)\left(1-\frac{e^2\epsilon^2}2\right)=\left(\frac1e-\epsilon+\frac{e\epsilon^2}2\right)\left(1-\frac{e^2\epsilon^2}2\right)=\frac1e-\epsilon+\frac{e^2\epsilon^3}2+O(\epsilon^4)$$
Hence, $x_2 -x_0\approx \frac{e^2\epsilon^3}2$
So, let's take the example $\epsilon = 0.001$. Then $$\left(e^{-e}\right)^{\left(e^{-e}\right)^{\left(\frac1e - 0.001\right)}} \approx 0.36687944240378767$$
$0.36687944240378767 - \left(\frac1e - 0.001\right) \approx 1.23235 \cdot10^{-9}$. However, with our approximation of the error, it should be $\frac{e^2(0.001)^3}2 = 3.69453 \cdot10^{-9}$. Why am I getting this discrepancy? Almost like I'm missing a factor of $3$ somewhere, as this is almost 3 times the actual result.

You need to take one more term (at least) in the expansion and you will arrive at $x_2-x_0=\frac{e^2\epsilon^3}6$
